# Typescript: use either the one or other interface based on property value

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to have a type that implements either the one or the other properties based on a given other property.

The type should have the following base structure:

```
interface LinkBase {
  label: string;
  isTextLink: boolean;
}
```

Depeinding on `isTextLink` it should have either `linkReference` or `linkText` as additional non-optional property:

```
// if isTextLink is false
export interface LinkWithLinkReference extends LinkBase {
  linkReference: LinkReference;
}

// if isTextLink is true
export interface LinkWithLinkText extends LinkBase {
   linkText: string;
}
```

I tried to create a union type where either the one or the other interface is allowed:

```
export type Link= LinkWithLinkReference | LinkWithLinkText;
```

but it does not take `isTextLink` value into account and in usage it gives me the following error:

**"Property 'linkText' does not exist on type 'Link'.   Property 'linkText' does not exist on type 'LinkWithLinkReference'."**

What would be the best way to create and use such type?

Comment: Just add `isTextLink: true` and `isTextLink: false` on each interface, and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isTextLink` can be removed.

To keep this simpler, the interface will do :

```
interface Link {
  label: string;
  content: LinkReference | string ;
}
```

typeof `content` will give you the link type.

But if you really want separation for some reason, [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) can help:

```
interface LinkBase<T> {
  label: string;
// content can be string or LinkReference
// content is an example name, use whatever name you want
  content: T ;
// other common attributes down here
}
```

```
export interface LinkWithLinkReference extends LinkBase<LinkReference> {
// other specific attributes down here

}
```

```
export interface LinkWithLinkText extends LinkBase<string> {
// other specific attributes down here

}
```